# How to calculate the limit of series involving logarithm

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

I'm trying to calculate the limit of the series

$S:=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \ln(1-2^{-i})$

and I'm not really sure how to do this. Maple is able to approximate the result but I don't think it is possible the express the result exactly. Any idea how to do approximate this result? My goal is to show that

$\exp(S)\geq 1/4$

Comment: $\exp\big(S\big)$ is [OEIS A$048651$](http://oeis.org/A048651).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** By concavity of the function $x \mapsto \ln(1 - x)$ the inequality $\ln(1 - x) \ge x  \ln\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)$ holds for all $x \in \left[0, \frac{1}{2}\right]$.

Comment: Brilliant hint! My only question is why does cocavity of $\ln(1-x)$ imply that $\ln (1-x) \geq x \ln(\frac{1}{4})$?

Comment: Use the definition of concavity between the points $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Let me see if I got this right; if $f(x)=\ln(1-x)$ is concave on $[0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and $z=(1-t)\cdot 0 + t \frac{1}{2}$ then $t=2z$. This implies that for $z$ between $0$ and $1/2$ it is true that

$f(z)\geq (1-t)f(0)+tf(1/2) \geq 2z f(1/2) =2z \ln (1/2)=z \ln (1/4)$

I guess I can even use sharp inequality in my case because $z\neq 0, \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: That is correct, although you actually can't use the sharp inequality for the first term in your sum.

Comment: That is true, but all other terms should be strictly greater, so the entire sum should be strictly greater.